# What are inputs of Keras layers and custom functions?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Sorry for a nub's question:

Having the NN that is trained in fit_generator mode, say something like:

```
Lambda(...)
```

or

```
Dense(...)
```

and the custom loss function, what are input tensors?
Am I correct expecting (batch size, previous layer's output) in case of a Lambda layer?
Is it going to be the same (batch size, data) in case of a custom loss function that looks like:

```
triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

Are y_true, y_pred in format (batch,previous layer's output) and (batch, true 'expected' data we fed to NN)?

Answer (score 0):

I would probaly duplicate the dense layers. Instead of having 2 layers with 128 units, have 4 layers with 64 units. The result is the same, but you will be able to perform the cross products better.

```
from keras.models import Model

#create dense layers and store their output tensors, they use the output of models 1 and to as input    
d1 = Dense(64, ....)(Model_1.output)   
d2 = Dense(64, ....)(Model_1.output)   
d3 = Dense(64, ....)(Model_2.output)   
d4 = Dense(64, ....)(Model_2.output)   

cross1 = Lambda(myFunc, output_shape=....)([d1,d4])
cross2 = Lambda(myFunc, output_shape=....)([d2,d3])

#I don't really know what kind of "merge" you want, so I used concatenate, there are 
Add, Multiply and others....
output = Concatenate()([cross1,cross2])
#use the "axis" attribute of the concatenate layer to define better which axis will 
be doubled due to the concatenation    

model = Model([Model_1.input,Model_2.input], output)
```

Now, for the lambda function:

```
import keras.backend as K

def myFunc(x):
    return x[0] * x[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> custom loss function, what are input tensors?

It depends on how you define your model `outputs`.

For example, let's define a simple model that returns the input unchanged.

```py
model = Sequential([Lambda(lambda x: x, input_shape=(1,))])
```

Let's use dummy input X and label Y

```py
x = [[0]]
x = np.array(x)

y = [[4]]
y = np.array(y)
```

If our **custom loss** function looks like this

```py
def mce(y_true, y_pred):
  print(y_true.shape)
  print(y_pred.shape)
  return K.mean(K.pow(K.abs(y_true - y_pred), 3))
```

```py
model.compile('sgd', mce)
```

and then we can see the **shape** of `y_true` and `y_pred` will be

```py
y_true:  (?, ?)
y_pred:  (?, 1)
```

---

However, for `triplet loss` the input for the loss function also can be received like this-

```py
ALPHA = 0.2
def triplet_loss(x):
    anchor, positive, negative = x

    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), 1)
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), 1)

    basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), ALPHA)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0), 0)

    return loss
# Source: https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/facenet.py
```

```py
def build_model(input_shape):
    # Standardizing the input shape order
    K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

    positive_example = Input(shape=input_shape)
    negative_example = Input(shape=input_shape)
    anchor_example = Input(shape=input_shape)

    # Create Common network to share the weights along different examples (+/-/Anchor)
    embedding_network = faceRecoModel(input_shape)

    positive_embedding = embedding_network(positive_example)
    negative_embedding = embedding_network(negative_example)
    anchor_embedding = embedding_network(anchor_example)

    loss = merge([anchor_embedding, positive_embedding, negative_embedding],
                 mode=triplet_loss, output_shape=(1,))
    model = Model(inputs=[anchor_example, positive_example, negative_example],
                  outputs=loss)
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=Adam())

    return model
```